# Do you know why dims [product 0] do not match the length of object [1] when trying pairw.anova

Tags: r, statistics, anova, tukey, data-comparison

I have this data:

```
a <- c(12, 14, 16, 12, 14, 16, 12, 14, 16)
b <- c(107.13, 83.01,  164.01, 113.01, 85.48,  86.08,  112.96, 82.18,  51.92)
```

`a` is the factor with 3 levels 12, 14  and 16 and `b` is my response variable

When I try to run and plot `pairs.anova`

```
pairw.anova(y=a, x=b,  conf.level = 0.95, method = "tukey", MSE = NULL, df.err = NULL)
```

I get this error:

> dims [product 0] do not match the length of object [1]

Do you know why is it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should add which package the `pairw.anova` function is from. As the question now stands, it's difficult to help you as you it's hard to reproduce your error.

Comment: Hi, I am using the library(asbio)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just swap the values of your arugments, since the response variable (quantitative) is probably `b`, and your categorical vector containing the groups is probably `a`.

And you have to ensure `a` is a factor:

```
library(asbio)

pairw.anova(y=b, x=factor(a),  conf.level = 0.95, 
            method = "tukey", MSE = NULL, df.err = NULL)
```

---

```
95% Tukey-Kramer confidence intervals 

               Diff      Lower    Upper Decision Adj. p-value
mu12-mu14  27.47667  -55.80207 110.7554   FTR H0     0.596586
mu12-mu16  10.36333   -72.9154 93.64207   FTR H0     0.923774
mu14-mu16 -17.11333 -100.39207  66.1654   FTR H0     0.809506
```

Comment: Hi Edward, yes you were right my mistake when I was typing, I did that that you show but I am still having the same problem.

Comment: Yes - I forgot to tell you to change `a` to a factor. Sorry about that!

Comment: Hi, hoping that everything is going well. I did that but I have the same problem, which libraries are you using? Thanks

Comment: I'm doing very well thanks! Umm, which libraries? Gosh, so long ago. I need to read this again.... Seems I used the __asbio__ package.

Comment: I am using library(tcltk)
library(mvtnorm)
library(asbio)
library(multcompView)

Comment: OK - so I think I\m using the `pairw.anova` function from the __asbio__ package because you didn't mention which package you used in the question (so I guessed). Try using that package.